# Not able to access MAAS WEB UI

Tags: maas

I'm getting **NO such resource**/ **NO such child resource** when accessing http://localhost:5240/MASS/ and http://10.0.2.15:5240/MASS/.

What i've done so far:

After normal installation, I've run the command sudo maas init and it was successful. After that, I've run sudo maas creteadmin and it was successful.

Comment: This is a stab in the dark, but what happens if you change 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1'?

Comment: @KGIII  tried it after your suggestion, but it's still showing NO such resource...